# java web security

Tags: java, security, oracle9i, materialized-views

Let me explain the problem.  So, there is a data base which is pivotal for many app and I need to keep it safe. Also, I do not want to access that data base directly. I think of using materialized view. Is that a good solution?
I need some suggestions about how to keep a master data base safe and synchronized.

,cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to do exactly ? Do all the application need to write on the database ?
If not for read only application you can use View in your database.

Otherwise the best way to keep your database safe it's to use constraint when creating your table.

Comment: To be more specific, our team is afraid of accessing the master data base directly because it can make the data less safer. That is why we are pondering to use materialized views in order of not accessing the master data base. Do you see our points? We just wish to keep the master data base safer because it is important to many other applications. Even though we have backup, a downtime to recovery that database will be unwelcome. Even the app prevent sql injection execution, we are afraid of any issue happen because of security vulnerability. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok, I understand but sooner or later you have to duplicate the data from your materialized view to your table. Materialized view is much more used to obtain greater performance than for security issue

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different approach. Make a copy of your database and use your application against this copy during a QA / Pilot phase. Once you know your application is stable and doesn't introduce security or stability concerns, then you can start using your production database.

Adding a materialized view would probably be difficult to work with as you would need to inspect each updates before manually synchronizing with the master database. And since there will be significant delay between the updates and the synch you run into potential collision issues.